# ¿Como combinar tres arrays en PHP al hacer un match de las claves iguales?

Tags: php, json, php7

Tengo 3 arrays en PHP que quiero poner en uno al igualarse las claves e incluyendo nuevas claves para los sub-arrays. Tengo estos arrays:

**Array de ID's**

```
{
    [0]=> int(1)
    [1]=> int(2)
    [2]=> int(3)
    [3]=> int(4)
    [4]=> int(5)
}
```

**Array de Nombres**

```
{
    [1]=> string('Lucas')
    [2]=> string('Jorge')
}
```

**Array de Fechas**

```
{
    [2]=> string('11 de Mayo')
    [3]=> string('7 de Septiembre')
}
```

**RESULTADO DESEADO**

1. Quiero combinarlos de forma que se pongan en grupos al tener un match entre las claves (los keys). For ejemplo Jorge tiene clave 2, asi que deberia ir con ID = 2 y Fecha 11 de Mayo.
2. Poner claves que indiquen qué tipo de dato es (id, nombre, fecha).

```
{
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass) {
        ["id"]=> int(1)
    },
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass) {
        ["id"]=> int(2),
        ["nombre"]=> string('Lucas')
    },
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass) {
        ["id"]=> int(3),
        ["nombre"]=> string('Jorge'),
        ["fecha"]=> string('11 de Mayo')
    },
    [3]=>
    object(stdClass) {
        ["id"]=> int(4),
        ["fecha"]=> string('7 de Septiembre')
    },
    [4]=>
    object(stdClass) {
        ["id"]=> int(5)
    },
}
```

Comment: No es muy clara tu pregunta, sobre todo debes decir cuáles son los criterios para **asociar** y/o **agrupar** los datos.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano por el comentario. Abajo del "RESULTADO DESEADO" he incluido un ejemplo. Creo que ahora estara mas clara. Avisame si puedo corregir mas!

Comment: OK, ahora sí se entiende.

Comment: OJO, este resultado deseado no cuadra con los datos que das: `object(stdClass) {
        ["id"]=> int(5),
        ["fecha"]=> string('7 de Septiembre')
    }`, según eso, el `id` es `5` pero debería ser `4` ¿no?

Comment: @A.Cedano Toda la razon, ahora lo corrijo! Gracias! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes combinar los datos haciendo lo siguiente:

1. Creas un array final donde se juntarán todos (`$allData`)
2. Partes del array de IDS, que es el más completo
3. Dentro de la lectura del array de IDS, creas un array temporal (`$tmpArray`), donde pones el `id`, dado que habrá siempre un `id`. Luego, buscas tanto en el array de nombres como en el de fechas si hay un valor con la clave actual (`1,2,3`...), si los hay los agregas también a `$tmpArray`. Y luego agregas `$tmpArray` a `$allData`.

Este sería el código:

```
/*Estos serían los datos que tienes*/
$arrIDs=array (1,2,3,4,5);
$arrNames=array(1=>'Lucas', 2=>'Jorge');
$arrDates=array(2=>'11-05',4=>'07-09');

/*Array que guardará el contenido combinado*/
$allData=array();

foreach($arrIDs as $k=>$v){
    $tmpArray=array('id'=>$v);
    if(isset($arrNames[$v]) ) {
        $tmpArray['name']=$arrNames[$v];
    } 
    if(isset($arrDates[$v]) ) {
        $tmpArray['fecha']=$arrDates[$v];
    }     
    $allData[] =$tmpArray;   
}
```

**Prueba:**

```
print_r($allData);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Lucas
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Jorge
            [fecha] => 11-05
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [fecha] => 07-09
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
        )

)
```

Para convertirlo a objeto, puedes hacerlo una vez creado  `$allData`, o crearlo y llenarlo siendo ya un objeto. Eso te lo dejo a ti, es muy fácil hacerlo.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solucion ! :)